# How to post a form containing more than 100 fields to MVC action using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Description:

My cshtml page has a form containing more than 100 fields. I want to submit that form to mvc action using ajax.

Code:

```
 var LoadFilters = function (data) {
        var formData;
        if (!showAll) {
            formData = $("#SearchForm").serializeArray();
        }
        var url = $.url("load-pp-transaction-filters") + "?buyerSk=" + data;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: formData,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#pp-transaction-filters").html(msg);
                $("#pp-transaction-filters").css("display", "block");
            },
            error: function (e)
            {
               console.log(e.responseText)
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm getting 404.15 error always, How to deal with it?

Comment: 404 is not found. Do you know basic http codes?

Comment: Have you tried `@HTML` forms you can get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms)

Comment: @Chisko yes I know, I'm getting 404.15 , it's because of querystring lengths is more than allowed. So I read about some configuration to deal with it, but I'm wondering that is there any other way to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

First check your URL is correct as 404 error is for URL not matched.

Secondly, if You have to use Post if you are submitting data as below:

```
var model = { 
    Name :"Shyju", 
    Location:"Detroit", 
    Interests : ["Code","Coffee","Stackoverflow"]
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function (res) {
    $("#SomeDivToShowTheResult").html(res);
});


public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public string Name {set;get;}
    public string Location {set;get;}
    public List<string> Interests {set;get;}
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult IndexPartial([FromBody] DashboardViewModel m)
{
    return PartialView("_IndexPartial",m);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is that you use `GET` in `Ajax` to get data,but `GET` method have limited length.

There are two ways to do it:

a. If you are using `IIS`, you can set the value of `requestLimits`,for more detail,check **[Request Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/)**

b. Change your `Ajax` method from `GET` to `POST`

```
 var LoadFilters = function (data) {
        var formData;
        if (!showAll) {
            formData = $("#SearchForm").serializeArray();
        }
        var url = $.url("load-pp-transaction-filters") + "?buyerSk=" + data;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#pp-transaction-filters").html(msg);
                $("#pp-transaction-filters").css("display", "block");
            },
            error: function (e)
            {
               console.log(e.responseText)
            }
        });
    }
```

usually `POST` method can hold more parameters,but if your fields are too much,it can still not work,then you also need to change the `requestLimits`